# Angular add element dynamically inside controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use the typeahead functionality from Sandeep Panda

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-typeahead-widget-with-angularjs/

Next I want to create from the selected value, a draggable element.
The code, calls onItemSelected() when the value is selected.
Now, how can I use angular to dynamically add the draggable to the DOM?
jQuery (as seen below) works just fine, but I would like to use angular as much as possible.

```
App.controller('TypeAheadController',function($scope,dataFactory){
dataFactory.get('states.json').then(function(data){
    $scope.items=data;
});
$scope.name="";
$scope.onItemSelected=function(){
    console.log('selected='+$scope.name);
    //CREATE NEW DRAGGABLE ELEMENT
    //Currently jquery is used for adding the element and make it draggable
    $('body').append("<div id='state' class='btn-draggable'>"+$scope.name+"</div>");
    $('#state').draggable();
}});
```

UPDATE:

Currently the controller looks like this:

```
App.controller('TypeAheadController',function($scope){

$scope.items = [
{name: 'Jan', id: 0, reject: true},
{name: 'Piet', id: 1},
{name: 'Klaas', id: 2},
{name: 'Henk', id: 3 }
];

$scope.name="";
$scope.onItemSelected=function(){
    $scope.enabled = true;
}});
```

and the directive looks like this:

```
App.directive('draggable', function() {
return {
restrict:'A',
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.draggable();

    scope.$watch('enabled', function (val) {
    element.draggable(val === true ? 'enable' : 'disable');
    });
}
```

};});

and the DIV:

```
<div id='draggable-{{item.id}}' class='btn-draggable' ng-repeat="item in items" enabled="false" draggable>{{items.name}}</div>
```

So in stead of jQuery actually adding the draggable element, now the element already exists and is controller by the directive (enabled/disabled). However I still have trouble referencing the right element after the typeahead functionality gives a certain value.

Right now, i do  $scope.enabled, but that is not specific for an element. Though the directive picks it up and enables/disables all draggables... How can I set this up so that only the selected value from typeahead becomes a draggable?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify the DOM manually like you do when using jQuery.

You can create a directive that wraps draggable functionally and takes as an argument the selected value, let's say your directive is

```
<my-draggable value="value"></my-draggable>
```

Now all you have to do is to use `ng-if` or `ng-show` and define in which cases this element appears. please note that in case your "directive" uses an isolated scope, you'll have to wrap the the directive in another element and put `ng-if` on it.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe the code for your directive example is missing?